# Maximum count of Azure Event Hub Authorization Rules (Shared access policies)?

Tags: azure-eventhub

Is there a limit on the count of  Authorization Rules (Shared access policies) an Azure Event Hub can have?

Answer (score 2):

The number of authorization rules per namespace just can be 12. If the number is larger than 12, the subsequent requests for authorization rule creation are rejected. For more details, please refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-quotas#common-limits-for-all-tiers)